# Serve a different SCSS file based on the text direction property

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, sass

I simply have two SCSS files. One called `app.scss` and the other `app-rtl.scss`.

The differences between them is that one has SCSS files that handle right to left (import rtl files). What I'm trying to solve is that once the `dir` is rtl, then I wanna use the other file (`app-rtl.scss`).

I'm using Node (mainly API) in the backend and React in the frontend.

I would very much appreciate it if someone has a suggestion on what I could do.

**Update**

Just to clarify a few things. I've used create-react-app package then ejected to add SCSS. This is how I'm currently getting the stylesheet (one style sheet)

`index.js`

```
import '../scss/app.scss'; // this where I'm getting all the styles.
```

And here is what that file looks like.

`app.scss`

```
// Override default value for $dir in directional
$dir: ltr;

// Import helpers from directional
@import "base/directional";

@import "base/variables";

// Import helpers from bootestrap
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/root";
@import "bootstrap/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/images";
//@import "bootstrap/code";
@import "bootstrap/grid";
//@import "bootstrap/tables";
@import "bootstrap/forms";
//@import "bootstrap/buttons";
@import "bootstrap/transitions";
@import "bootstrap/dropdown";
@import "bootstrap/button-group";
@import "bootstrap/input-group";
@import "bootstrap/custom-forms";
@import "bootstrap/nav";
@import "bootstrap/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/card";
.
.
.
```

The `app-rtl.scss` has a bunch of scss files for right to left.

If I wanna use Webpack, how do I compile it to two CSS files then apply what was suggested for me in the answer? If handling this from Node, I'm also file with that approach.

P.S: I'm not that familiar with Webpack but I think this is how to does the job:

```
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              require.resolve('css-loader'),
              require.resolve('fast-sass-loader')
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              require.resolve('css-loader'),
            ]
          },
```

Comment: @isherwood thank you for your quick response, It's pretty much the text direction. For example, by default, it's left to right (ltr).

If it's rtl, then everything in the HTML will render from right to left.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp

Comment: this usually done via a different indicator like a url param rather than a DOM attribute. i think its easier to implement (both on the server side and clinet)

Comment: I understand what text direction is. I'm not clear on what you're checking to determine RTL status. What's the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating two different CSS files using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` npm package.

```
      {
        test: /style\/.*\.scss$/,
        use: styleCss.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /app-rtl\/.*\.scss$/,
        use: styleRtlCss.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /commonStyle\/.*\.scss$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
```

Then loaded one of the style based on the dir's value

`Routers.js`

```
class Routes extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        stylePath: loadStyle(props.direction)
    }
    const defaultLanguage = props.customer.defaultLang || LOCAL_LANGUAGES[0].code;

    props.InitializeDefaultLang(defaultLanguage);
    props.getVehicles();
    props.getCountriesOnly(defaultLanguage);
    props.changeDefaultDirection(defaultLanguage);
}
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    if (prevProps.direction !== this.props.direction) {
      this.setState({
        stylePath: loadStyle(this.props.direction)
      })
    }
  }

return (
     <div>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={this.state.stylePath} />
     </div>
 )
```

`config.js`

```
export default function loadStyle(direction) {

  if (direction === 'ltr') {
    return '/style.css';

  } else {
    return '/style-rtl.css';
  }
}
```

Hope this helps if anyone ran into the same issue. The only problem here is that it takes forever to switch the style.

I'm gonna just leave that and use Node instead

Answer (score 1):

I'd have 3 stylesheets one for normal direction a shared styles file to be imported into both and then the rtl stylesheet

```
// shared.scss
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/root";
@import "bootstrap/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/images";
@import "bootstrap/code";
@import "bootstrap/grid";
@import "bootstrap/tables";
@import "bootstrap/forms";
@import "bootstrap/buttons";
@import "bootstrap/transitions";
@import "bootstrap/dropdown";
@import "bootstrap/button-group";
@import "bootstrap/input-group";
@import "bootstrap/custom-forms";
@import "bootstrap/nav";
@import "bootstrap/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/card";
@import "base/variables";

//default.scss
@import "shared.scss"

//rtl.scss
@import "shared.scss"
@import "base/directional";
```

then you can import them in your react app like so

```
if (RTL) {
  require('rtl.scss')
} else {
  require('default.scss')
}
```

> refer to this answer 
>   [React RTL. Conditional Import CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650466/react-rtl-conditional-import-css)

Comment: Where in this are you checking the RTL boolean value?

Comment: I assumed it was a user provided value or i mean you can always use getComputedStyle or something to get the value set as default.

Comment: @JoeWarner thank you for your response. Sorry, was heading home. I'll have to try it and let you know. 

The thing is I'm using Webpack, not entirely sure how to compile 2 SCSS files and just use one.

This is what I mean:

my `index.js` file
`import '../scss/app.scss';` // this is how I'm getting the style sheet for the ltr. What you showed me has given me a good idea on how I could go about solving it

Comment: oh right, well then yeah your asking a few questions then i'll try edit my answer soon as i think you need to understand a few steps to grasp this

Comment: Thank you @JoeWarner. 

I've just updated my question to make a bit clearer.

Comment: i'm abit confused what are you expecting to happen as webpack is build time thing and wont be run time you can do some dynamic requiring on style sheets though

Comment: @AhmedShaaban i've updated my answer hope this helps

Comment: @JoeWarner thanks again, I tried your suggestion but it adds both files. 

`
export default function loadStyle(direction) {
  if (direction === 'ltr') {
    require('../../scss/style/app.scss');
  } else {
    require('../../scss/app-rtl/app-rtl.scss');
  }
}
`

Comment: Do you have other suggestions? Like Maybe it's easier to handle that from the server side?

Comment: @AhmedShaaban what do you mean it includes both files do you mean they're both built or both are 
loaded on the page?

Comment: @JoeWarner they are both loaded on the page. I'm quite confused with webpack.

Comment: @AhmedShaaban i'm at work but will investigate and change my answer :)

Comment: @JoeWarner thank you heaps. I really appreciate it. This is like something I never faced before and I'm doing it for work lol

Comment: i mean how many styles does it take to turn it from ltr to rtl if its not alot id just suggest bundling both and adding a class on the body but this is achievable just need to look into it a bit more

Comment: @AhmedShaaban also does this need to be set just on load or can it be changeable when you're on the page?

Comment: @JoeWarner sorry for the late reply. I just wanna use it on load (once a user loads the web app). If click another language, I was trying to do something like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={`${this.state.stylePath}`} />`

Comment: The problem with this approach, it's in my root component but it loads everything just for a second without a style