# Loading different CSS base on URL

Tags: reactjs

Our web application is branded and our branded is dynamic. it means the admin can add a new brand on the fly (upload CSS and logo and the new brand name).

Our branded logic is based on URL. We want to have different CSS files for each brand.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('.xyaz.com') >= 0)
  //load 'App.xyaz.css'
```

how we can load CSS dynamically in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspire from answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650466/react-rtl-conditional-import-css)

Implementing an HOC (High Order Component)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const withBrandedCss = (WrapComponent) => {
  return class extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
 const domain = "xyz" // fetch domain name here and used it if your CSS name convention is supported;
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("xyz.com") > 0) require("../../BrandedCss/App.1.css");
      else require("../../BrandedCss/App.css");
    }

    render(){
        return (<WrapComponent {...this.props}></WrapComponent>)
    }
  };
};

export default withBrandedCss;
```

Usage:

```
export default withBrandedCss(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible to do from JavaScript like following:

```
const styleSheetLink = document.createElement("link");
styleSheetLink.type="text/css";
styleSheetLink.rel="stylesheet";
styleSheetLink.charset="UTF-8";
styleSheetLink.href="/App.xyaz.css";
document.head.appendChild(styleSheetLink);
```

but I am not sure that it a "right"™ way to do this in general