# Not able to import multiple css without applying in React App

Tags: jquery, reactjs, css

I have a react app where i have created two stylesheets, one with daylight light colors and other with night light dark colors. While i am trying to import both the later one gets applied automatically. I just want to import them and not apply by default. Based on some condition i'll be applying one of them .

Here is the code :

```
import Daylight from './daylight.css';
import Nightlight from './nightlight.css';
```

I tried require also, that also doesn't helps

```
const Daylight = require('./daylight.css');
const Nightlight = require('./nightlight.css');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React RTL. Conditional Import CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650466/react-rtl-conditional-import-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing your CSS at all is applying it right away.

You'd probably be better off if you arranged your CSS in such a way that you could conditionally apply a single class to a parent element that would then apply styles from `nightlight.css`.

e.g. inside `nightlight.css`

```
.night button {
  /* styles for your buttons when they're in a night container */
}

.night p {
   /* styles for your ps when they're in a night container */
}

etc
```

and then have some code in your component to either add or remove the `night` class depending on whether or not darkmode is enabled.

Comment: No problem, there are other ways to achieve something closer to exactly what you're looking for though, I'd look into the styled-components library. This allows you to more easily conditionally apply CSS to components and still allows you to write more or less regular CSS syntax.

https://www.styled-components.com/

Also! If my answer helped, consider approving it to help the next person who comes along looking for help with this :)